# My c++ code failed on a macro+template compilation, why this error?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compilation, macros

I was using old version of gcc so I tried to implement several useful type_traits elements, like is_base_of and static_assert, like this:

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct my_is_base_of{
    struct Yes{char _;};
    struct No{char _[2];};
    static Yes _test(const Base*);
    static No _test(void*);
    static const bool value=sizeof(_test((Derived*)0))==sizeof(Yes);
};

template<bool b>struct _static_assert_test{static char _;};
template<>struct _static_assert_test<false>{};
#define _static_assert(x) _static_assert_test<x>::_

struct Base{};
struct Derived : Base {};
struct C {};
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<my_is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value<<std::endl;
    _static_assert(sizeof(int)==4);
    _static_assert(my_is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value);//fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Well, the 1st line in main functions compiles and prints "true". So does the 2nd line. But the 3rd line fails to compile. My gcc 4.1.2 says:

> derive.cpp:22:54: error: macro "_static_assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
>
> derive.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> derive.cpp:22: error: ‘_static_assert’ was not declared in this scope

How to fix my case? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth noting that C++ macros are expanded before the parsing phase of compilation and this is done by a textual replacement of each parameter of the macro to matched places. `my_is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value` is here interpreted by the macro as two parameters as it uses comma operator: `my_is_base_of<Base` becomes first parameter and `Derived>::value` becomes second. This behavior is precisely due to the fact that macro does not (cannot) perform parsing and as such it is unable to know that comma is used in the context of template parameters. To workaround the problem you need to put the statement in parenthesis:

```
_static_assert((my_is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value));
```

compiles without problems.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that the preprocessor happens before the c++ parser, and that the preprocessor does not recognise any c++ tokens.